# How to handle categorical data for preprocessing in Machine Learning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, feature-selection

This may be a basic question, I have a categorical data and I want to feed this into my machine learning model. my ML model accepts only numerical data. What is the correct way to convert this categorical data into numerical data.

My Sample DF:

```
  T-size Gender  Label
0      L      M      1
1      L      M      1
2      M      F      1
3      S      F      0
4      M      M      1
5      L      M      0
6      S      F      1
7      S      F      0
8      M      M      1
```

I know this following code convert my categorical data into numerical

Type-1:

```
df['T-size'] = df['T-size'].cat.codes
```

Above line simply converts category from 0 to N-1. It doesn't follow any relationship between them.

For this example I know S < M < L. What should I do when I have want to convert data like above.

Type-2:

In this type I No relationship between M and F. But I can tell that When `M` has more probability than `F`. i.e., **sample to be 1  / Total number of sample**

for Male,

**(4/5)**

for Female,

**(2/4)**

WKT,

**(4/5) > (2/4)**

How should I replace for this kind of column?

Can I replace M with (4/5) and F with (2/4) for this problem?

What is the proper way to dealing with column?

help me to understand this better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to encode categorical data, some of them depend on exactly what you plan to do with it. For example, one-hot-encoding which is easily the most popular choice is an [extremely poor choice](https://roamanalytics.com/2016/10/28/are-categorical-variables-getting-lost-in-your-random-forests/) if you're planning on using a decision tree / random forest / GBM.

Regarding your t-shirts above, you can give a pandas categorical type an order:

```
df['T-size'].astype(pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(['S','M','L'],ordered=True)).
```

if you had set up your tshirt categorical like that then your `.cat.codes` method would work perfectly. It also means you can easily use scikit-learn's `LabelEconder` which fits neatly into pipelines.

Regarding you encoding of gender, you need to be very careful when using your target variable (your `Label`). You don't want to do this encoding before your train-test split otherwise you're using knowledge of your unseen data making it not truly unseen. This gets even more complicated if you're using cross-validation as you'll need to do the encoding with in each CV iteration (i.e. new encoding per fold). If you want to do this, I recommend you check out [TargetEncoder](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/targetencoder.html) from skcontribs Category Encoders but again, be sure to use this within an sklearn `Pipeline` or you will mess up the train-test splits and leak information from your test set into you training set.

Comment: What is the importance of `ordered`. i.e., what is the difference between  df['T-size'].astype('category') and `df['T-size'].astype(pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(['S','M','L'],ordered=True))`

Comment: Well, you said you wanted to be sure that S<M<L, so that's what ordered does for you

Comment: yeah got it ;-)

Comment: For a clarification in `You don't want to do this encoding before your train-test split otherwise you're using knowledge of your unseen data making it not truly unseen.` this statement `this encoding` represents which encoding? you mean my assumption of encoding right? or you mean something other?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah technically, any encoding, But particularly any encoding that uses the target variable or the distribution of the variable being encoded.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah the target and frequency coding approaches are discussed here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irkV4sYExX4#action=share

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, if you have a small number of categories, you could `map` the column with a dictionary. In this way you can set an order:

```
d = {'L':2, 'M':1, 'S':0}
df['T-size'] = df['T-size'].map(d)
```

Output:

```
   T-size Gender  Label
0       2      M      1
1       2      M      1
2       1      F      1
3       0      F      0 
4       1      M      1
5       2      M      0
6       0      F      1
7       0      F      0
8       1      M      1
```

For the second question, you can use the same method, but i would leave the 2 values for males and females `0` and `1`. If you need just the category and you dont have to make operations with the values, a values is equal to another.

Comment: thanks for the answer, here you used mapping values for s->0, M->2, L->2 May I know why did you choose 0,1,2. If it represents weight can I use 10, 20, 30 respectively. will it make any difference in my model

Comment: I would start from the smallest value `0`, and increase till the biggest

Comment: I'm really confused with what value to assign. Is replacing a scalar value to the category sufficient to deal with categorical data?

Comment: Yes it is enough

Comment: sorry for the repeated question, I'm really wondering, Don't I need to give weight explicitly?

Comment: No, you shouldnt. If you are using those values just as categories, use integer

Comment: Why I shouldn't? What is the problem I'll face I.e., For the second type, If I use (4/5) for `M` and (2/4) for `F` What kind of problem I will face?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah you'll face a data leak if you do that when you try split out a training set later. Also, it's not a bad idea to scale your encoding by taking a weighted average between your 'probability' encoding and a frequency encoding

Comment: @Dan - Thanks for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a hierarchy in your size parameter, you may consider using a linear mapping for it. This would be :

```
size_mapping = {"S": 1, "M":2 , "L":3}

#mapping to the DataFrame
df['T-size_num'] = df['T-size'].map(size_mapping)
```

This allows you to treat the input as numerical data while preserving the hierarchy

And as for the gender, you are misconceiving the repartition and the preproces. If you already put the repartition as an input, you will introduce a bias in your data. You must consider that Male and female as two distinct categories regardless of their existing repartition. You should map it with two different numbers, but without introducing proportions.

```
df['Gender_num'] = df['Gender'].map({'M':0 , 'F':1})
```

For a more detailed explanation and a coverage of more specificities than your question, I suggest reading [this article regarding categorical data in Machine Learning](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/easy-methods-deal-categorical-variables-predictive-modeling/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for first question, you assigns 1, 2, 3 may I know the reson behind that?

Comment: The relationship of the values of your size parameters are unknown, so I assume it to be linear. And since sizes are positive entities, I took your minimum value to be greater than 0. It makes sure that the M size is a multiple of the S size (which is also true for the L size of course), and it would not be true for S=0, M=1 and L=3

Comment: I'm curious to know instead of `1, 2, 3` Can I use `10, 20, 30` or `5, 10, 15` ?

Comment: Yes you could. The most important part is the way you model the relationship between your elements. If it is set to be linear with c=3a and b=2a, the patterns you will find in your data will remain the same whether you use 1, 2 and 3 or any other triplet that preserve that same linear relationship.

Answer (score 1):

It might be overkill for the M/F example, since it's binary - but if you are ever concerned about mapping a categorical into a numerical form, then consider [one hot encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). It basically stretches your single column containing *n* categories, into *n* binary columns.

So a dataset of:

```
Gender
M
F
M
M
F
```

Would become

```
Gender_M    Gender_F
1           0
0           1
1           0
1           0
0           1
```

This takes away any notion of one thing being more "positive" than another - an absolute must for categorical data with more than 2 options, where there's no transitive A > B > C relationship and you don't want to smear your results by forcing one into your encoding scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understood the first part, But I failed to understand `an absolute must for categorical data with more than 2 options, where there's no transitive A > B > C relationship and you don't want to smear your results by forcing one into your encoding scheme.` this point. can you make me clear.

Comment: So you've outlined two types of categorical variable in your example, {S,M,L} is transitive, since you can assign them an order. {M,F} isn't transitive, but it is binary, so coding to {0,1} is probably ok. Another type of categorical variable is one where there are more than 2 options, but which are not orderable (i.e. not transitive) - so {Vanilla, Strawberry, Grape} might be the options in a categorical variable, but if transformed to {0,1,2} a skew is introduced, suggesting that Strawberry exists "between" Vanilla and Grape when no such relationship exists outside of the arbitrary coding.

Comment: Great explanation, It's really appreciated. For this `{Vanilla, Strawberry, Grape}` one hot encoding solve the problem right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There's nothing stopping you from using it for `{M,F}` too. One-hot encoding has the disadvantage of expanding the dimensionality of your data, which can be a problem when the number of categories in a field gets large, but bearing that in mind, it's usually a good general-use option.